# Jquery getting the nearest left and right value in an array

Tags: jquery, arrays

i have an array 
`var theArray = [ 1, 3, 8, 10, 13 ];`

i want to determine the nearest value of the user input in the array.
if user in put 2. it should display 1 as the nearest value left and 3 as the nearest value right.

ive tried this

```
var goal = parseFloat($("#searchbar").val());
        var theArray = [ 1, 3, 8, 10, 13 ];

        $.each(theArray, function(index, value){
             if (closestleft == null || Math.abs(this - goal) < Math.abs(closestleft - goal)) {
            closestleft = this;
          }
        });

        alert(closestleft);
```

the code above will give me the desired output which is 1.

the problem is i cant get the other output which is 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works.

```
<script>

        var goal = parseFloat($("#searchbar").val());

        // var goal = 2;
        var closestleft = NaN;
        var closestright = NaN;
        var theArray = [ 1, 3, 8, 10, 13 ];

        $.each(theArray, function(index, value){
           if ((isNaN(closestleft) || Math.abs(this - goal) < Math.abs(closestleft - goal)) && this < goal) closestleft = this;
           if ((isNaN(closestright) || Math.abs(this - goal) < Math.abs(closestright - goal)) && this > goal) closestright = this;
        });

        alert('ClosestLeft = ' + closestleft + ', ClosestRight = ' + closestright);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

check this:

```
var theArray = [ 1, 3, 8, 10, 13 ];
var userinput = 2;
var left = right= -1;
for(var i in theArray) 
   if(userinput <= theArray[i] && i > 0) {
      left = theArray[i-1];
      right = theArray[i];
      break; 
   }
console.log(right,left);
```

Comment: I guess here for loop is not needed, By using index you can use achieve   left = theArray[i-1];
right = theArray[i];